# Does GroovyShell cache the compiled scripts?

Tags: groovy, groovyshell

I plan to embed groovy in my application and use [GroovyShell](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Embedding+Groovy) programatically - I will run the same script several times with different parameters.

Does GroovyShell caches the compiled script or does it work only as a stateless interpreter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it caches the scripts.  Take a look at the code.  Unless the comments are wrong, the scripts are not cached.  [Line 511](http://groovy.codehaus.org/xref/groovy/lang/GroovyShell.html#511).

Comment: Thanks, more of a reason to go with the GroovyClassLoader and generate classes on the fly.